# A name for a particular covering map?

Tags: general-topology, terminology, conformal-geometry

The quotient space of $\mathbb C$ obtained by identifying points differing by a Gaussian integer is topologically a torus.  The map that takes each point in $\mathbb C$ to its corresponding point in the quotient space is a covering map.  But the concept of "covering map" is, as far as I know, purely topological.  These spaces have more structure than their topologies and in particular, this mapping is *conformal*.  And I just might also want to view these as metric spaces with the usual Euclidean metric on this covering space and the shortest-path metric on the quotient space.

Is there some standard name for **this particular** covering map?  If not, what name for it would be appropriate?

Comment: I inappropriately included the word "universal" before "coverning map" in the initial version of this question.  I plead not guilty by reason of temporary guilt and hereby instruct everyone not to be aware of what I did.

Comment: How about "the mod $\mathbb{Z}[\hspace{-0.02 in}i\hspace{.02 in}]$ map"? $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer : Perhaps.  But I wonder if there's something a tad more poetic? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: One could put a hyphen in. $\:$ I can't think of anything else. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: [Flat Torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus#Flat_torus)?

Comment: @PyRulez : This is a covering _of_ the flat torus.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Actually you could say that its "the universal covering map of the flat torus". Is that poetic enough?